# How to remove leading and trailing spaces from a shell variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, variable

I have variable named tablename and it has leading and trailing spaces (for example,

```
tablename= yyy
```

). I want to remove the leading and trailing spaces (OUTPUT :

```
tablename=yyy
```

) and write this variable to file without any space using shell script.

Comment: Is this a shell source file that you'd like to modify, or do you have an actual variable with spaces in its value that you'd like to remove?

Comment: Hi @Chai how you want to remove trailing and leading spaces from a variable. There should be no space in a variable? sorry i have to down vote

Comment: Why is this question closed? It is quite clear to me, though it can be enhanced.

Answer (score 4):

```
var='    A  B C  '
```

with `zsh`:

```
trim=${${var%${var##*[^[:blank:]]}}#${${var%${var##*[^[:blank:]]}}%%[^[:blank:]]*}}
printf '++%s++\n' $trim
```

```
++A  B C++
```

with `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
trim=${var%%*([[:blank:]])}
trim=${trim##*([[:blank:]])}
printf '++%s++\n' "$trim"
```

```
++A  B C++
```

with any shell, you can use additional variables to save the leading and trailing blanks<sup>1</sup> (it's basically the same as the `zsh` solution but without nested operations):

```
trail=${var##*[^[:blank:]]}    # get trailing space
var=${var%${trail}}            # remove trailing space
lead=${var%%[^[:blank:]]*}     # get leading space
trim=${var#${lead}}            # remove leading space
printf '++%s++\n' "$trim"
```

```
++A  B C++
```

---

<sup>1: for clarity, I'm using two variables here to hold the leading and respectively the trailing blanks but one variable would do.</sup>

Comment: Neat. In zsh, this also works:
`var='  surrounded by spaces  '`
- `echo "++${var##[[:blank:]]##}++"` removes leading space
- `echo "++${var%%[[:blank:]]##}++"` removes trailing spaces

Comment: @verboze - indeed and it's shorter. You can always add it to the post via edit if you wish just don't forget it needs `setopt extendedglob` in order to work...

Comment: with `setopt extendedglob`, just do `${${var## #}%% #}`.

Answer (score 2):

As given in [your post in other site](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/280159-how-remove-leading-trailing-spaces-variable-shell-script.html):

```
tablename=${tablename// }
```

Comment: This is not quite right, because it removes *ALL* spaces from the string. OP only wanted to remove leading/trailing spaces

Answer (score 1):

The `read` command will trim leading and trailing whitespace characters (as defined by the value of `IFS`); you can use this with a here-document to trim spaces:

```
IFS=' ' read tablename <<EOF
$tablename
EOF
```

If you're using bash (not some brand X shell), you can simplify this with a here-string instead of a here-document:

```
IFS=' ' read tablename <<<"$tablename"
```

Note that since this assignment to `$IFS` is a prefix to the `read` command, it only applies to that one command and doesn't have to be reset afterward. Also, if you haven't otherwise messed with `$IFS` and want to trim any tabs as well as spaces, you don't need to set `IFS` at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "tablename =yyy" | tr -d ' '
tablename=yyy
```

Comment: This will remove spaces in the middle of the string, as well as at the ends.

Comment: @GordonDavisson variables with spaces in thier name are not a valid variables nor trailing spaces at the end of string(its value assuming you mean) without quoting used.

Comment: I understood the question as how to remove the leading and trailing spaces from the value of a variable (which was set somewhere earlier in the script), not from a string that looks like a variable assignment.